# Good alternative to reading from depth attachment (OpenGL ES 2.0)

Tags: c++, graphics, opengl-es

I have an engine running OpenGL ES 2.0. I have created a framebuffer object which has two color attachments and a depth attachment. When I perform renders to this buffer, the depth attachment is used for depth testing when subsequent writes are made to the color attachment. I want to use the information present in the depth attachment and store it in a color attachment. Is there a way I can store data in the second color attachment directly within the shader or at least a cheap way to copy the data from the depth attachment to the other color attachment on the native code once this information is available?

Comment: Have you considered simply writing `gl_FragCoord.z` to the other color attachment? `gl_FragData [1] = gl_FragCoord.z`? Of course you'd probably have to pack that into 4 channels to store the depth in OpenGL ES unless your color attachment is `GL_R32` (which I don't think ES 2.0 supports).

Answer (score 0):

No automatic way to do this. Subsequent render passes will have to just load the depth information via a normal texture() call in the shader.